# Symfony2 & Doctrine - Entending a base class entity - Problems when updating

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, entity, persist

I am using an entity and extending a base class to handle modified date, created date, and delete date -- along with a modifiedBy, createdBy, and deleteBy field.

When I create the record, it works fine and populates createdBy, and createdDate. But when I update, it does not set the modifiedBy... only the modified date -- Even though I explicity set modifiedBy before I `merge()`.

The base class has lifecycle callbacks (which set the date fields), and the controller is where I set the *By field (createdBy, modifiedBy, and deletedBy).

```
foreach ($form->get('analytics')->getData() as $analytic) {
    // Only set creator if not previously set
    if ($analytic->getCreatedBy() == null) {
        $analytic
            ->setPartner($partner)
            ->setCreatedBy($username);

        $em->persist($analytic);
    } else {
        $analytic->setModifiedBy($username);

        $em->merge($analytic);
    }
}
```

If I use `persist()` when updating, it copies the record (which is why I'm using `merge()`).

Comment: What if you replace the code in your else with `$analytic = $em->merge($analytic); $analytic->setModifiedBy($username);`? (basically inversing the 2 lines)

Comment: And then you need to call `$em->persist($analytic);`